Why do questions on NE not get as many votes as on other SE sites?
I just recently started using NE and it took me as a small suprise that questions here don't really get votes, while answers get votes as expected.
To be sure that this is the case I got the view/vote ratio of the top 15 questions from both NE and SO and I found out that on

NE on avg it takes 2455 views to get one vote, and on
SO on avg it takes 458 views to get one vote.

This is just an example, but it feels like other SE sites are more active on casting votes to questions.
I wonder how come there are hardly any votes on the NE questions?

It would be interesting to know if the views were active participants or casual passersby that cannot vote due to lack of reputation. The number of 2455 is probably a couple of orders of magnitude bigger than the number of active users on NE. The evidence suggests users on NE tend not to vote often, and that may be due to the fact that most questions on NE are off-topic and are closed. I try to vote (having cast them most votes by far), but I do miss some that should get a vote.

I can't speak for everyone (even the relatively few on NE), but to me, I vote on answers because that what SE is about - people come here for the answers; they find the questions mostly by Google. (if they can be bothered, rather than find NE and immediately ask away.) It rarely occurs to me to vote on questions because it's not a popularity contest. I browse by date, not votes ("popularity"), and read every question. I suspect most of the regulars aren't pay much attention to question ratings either, and NE is such a small exchange, questions are never going to get many votes anyway.
